# CSS on hover to show hidden text

Tags: html, css, text, hover, hidden

I've seen some other ways in the related question to do this but here is what I had a while ago and it sort of worked before but now does not at all. I have a big table and the last column is an image, and the desired behavior is it shows the text on hover.

Here is the CSS:

```
#freebie-table td[data-title]:hover:after {
   content: attr(data-title);
   padding: 4px 8px;
   color: #333;
   position: absolute;
   left: 70%;
   top: 100%;
   width: 150px;
   height: 200px;
   z-index: 20;
   /*white-space: nowrap; */
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
}
```

and here is an example of a TD element which has got the data-title attribute:

```
 <td data-title="THIS TEXT IS SUPPOSED TO APPEAR ON HOVER"><img src="images/click2read.png" alt="click 2 read" height="38" width="33" /></td>
```

Any idea why this doesn't work.  If no one answers I'll try the jquery way I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to tell, but looks like the element might be appearing outside of wherever you expect it. The `top` value of this element that appears on hover is `100%`. If you add `position: relative` to the `td`, the hidden thing will appear just below that `td`. Also make sure the table id is `#freebie-table`.

```css
#freebie-table td[data-title]:hover:after {
   content: attr(data-title);
   padding: 4px 8px;
   color: #333;
   position: absolute;
   left: 70%;
   top: 100%;
   width: 150px;
   height: 200px;
   z-index: 20;
   /*white-space: nowrap; */
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
} 

#freebie-table td {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table id="freebie-table">
  <tr>
  <td data-title="THIS TEXT IS SUPPOSED TO APPEAR ON HOVER"><img src="images/click2read.png" alt="click 2 read" height="38" width="33" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect!   Thanks!  I think I may have broken this code on purpose because those boxes were appearing in bad places!  :)

Comment: @TIXBRANCO awesome, you're welcome :) Btw, be sure to upvote helpful answers and mark the best one as the answer (the checkmark by answers) once the issue is resolved.